# updating h:dataTable passing a parameter via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

How can I use JSF dataTable to show rows of orderList items and on call of a jQuery function showOrderNum(orderNum)
update the datatable to show only the orders with that orderNum ?
The problem is letting the jquery function call the backing bean of dataTable passing a parameter.

Here is an example, the dataTable:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{order.orderList}" var="o">
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Order No."/>
                            </f:facet>
                            #{o.orderNo}
                        </h:column>

                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Product Name"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            #{o.productName}
                        </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Here is the backing bean order:

```
@ManagedBean(name="order")
@SessionScoped
public class OrderBean implements Serializable{

    private static final Order[] orderList = new Order[] {
        new Order(1, "Intel CPU"),
        new Order(2, "Harddisk 10TB")
    };

    public Order[] getOrderList() {

        return orderList;

    }

    public Order getOrderList(int id) {

        // return orderList item with id number = id

    }

    public static class Order{

        String orderNo;
        String productName;


        public Order(String orderNo, String productName) {
            this.orderNo = orderNo;
            this.productName = productName;
        }
        //getter and setter methods
    }
}
```

and here the jquery function which should let the dataTable update:

```
function showOrderNum(orderNum) {
    //update datatable passing orderNum parameter
}
```

Comment: This is JSF version 2.x right?

Comment: yes, forgot to mention it, I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Richfaces provides a4j:jsFunction to perform an ajax request from javascript itself. You can consider this if you are using richfaces.

Comment: I'll consider that, however I'd like to know the plain JSF way first. I think it must be possible to do something similar without using third party libraries

Comment: How are you calling showOrderNum(orderNum)? Is it getting called on value change somewhere?

Comment: on click of a button a modal popup opens where I select from a dropdown list of ordernums, on close of the modal dialog showOrderNum(orderNum) is called

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the following lines:

(Changes in xhtml)

```
<h:dataTable value="#{order.orderList}" var="o" id="resultsGrid">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Order No."/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:commandLink value="#{o.orderNo}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{order.selectedOrder}" value="#{o}" />
            <f:ajax render="resultsGrid" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:column>
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```

(Changes in bean)

```
@ManagedBean(name="order")
@SessionScoped
public class OrderBean implements Serializable{
    ...
    private Order selectedOrder;
    // getter and setter for selectedOrder

    public Order[] getOrderList() {
        if( selectedOrder == null ) return orderList;
        else return getOrderList(selectedOrder.getOrderNo());
    }

    ...
}
```

The `commandLink` will call the server with AJAX and populate `order.selectedOrder`. Its child `<f:ajax>` re-renders the grid, calling `getOrderList()`, which now sees that a filter is active and acts accordingly. There should also be a clear fiter button somewhere.

By the way, no need for jQuery with this.

Comment: The above is not flexible enough, I should indeed select a field of the dataTable itself while instead showOrderNum(orderNum) could be something else. I want the Jquery to call a function of the Bean and the dataTable to refresh with this data.

Comment: I don't quite get what you want; however you can use JSF 2 Javascript API as described in chapters 13 and 14 of the specification (especially ch. 14). That is, if `<f:ajax>` is not enough.